# Is it ok to sign/distibute an app on behalf of customers so they can beta test?

Tags: iphone, sign

I am writing an app that I want some customers to beta test (enterprises with potentially more than 100 users). If the customers are willing to give me their adhoc or inhouse distribution certificate/profile - is it ok for me to sign my app with their certificate so they can distribute the app to their employees?
B2B could have worked but it costs too much money and I am not ready to go to the appstore yet.

Thanks in advance.